# How to get netmask and default gateway of adapters in WEC2013

Tags: windows-embedded-compact

The function [GetAdaptersInfo](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/gg154286(v=winembedded.70).aspx)  allows to retrieve the address information including netmask and default gateway for all adapters.

This function is deprecated since [Windows Embedded Compact 7](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/gg154286(v=winembedded.70).aspx). 
The "Functionality To Use Instead" list the function GetAdaptersAddresses as a replacement. But this function doesn't report netmask and default gateway.

How can I get the netmask and the default gateway of the network adapters?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`GetAdaptersAddresses` returns a linked list of [IP_ADAPTER_ADDRESSES](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/hardware/ee493670%28v=winembedded.60%29) structs.

Within each `IP_ADAPTER_ADDRESSES`, the `FirstUnitcastAddress` field points to a list of [IP_ADAPTER_UNICAST_ADDRESSES](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/hardware/ee494101%28v=winembedded.60%29) structs.

Within each `IP_ADAPTER_UNICAST_ADDRESSES` there is a field called `OnLinkPrefixLength`, which specifies the netmask as the length, in bits, of the network part of the IP address. Note that this field is not documented for WEC2013 (it is for desktop Windows, though).

To convert `OnLinkPrefixLength` to a ULONG mask, use [ConvertLengthToIpv4Mask](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/gg159408.aspx).

Gateway addresses are provided through the `FirstGatewayAddress` field in each `IP_ADAPTER_ADDRESSES` struct.